# Using DynamicResource Style and DataTrigger for button in XAML

Tags: xaml, datatrigger, dynamicresource

I am using predefined style like `Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}"`

that cannot be modified and I need to enable/disable a `Button` via `DataTrigger`.

It seems like is impossible to do?

> The error is:  The property 'Style' is set more than once.

```
<Button Content="Guardar" Width="100"  Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}" Name="SaveTemplateATM" Click="SaveTemplateATM_Click">
  <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                       <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=UserName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="0">
                           <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                       </DataTrigger>                                           
             </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
  </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only set the style attribute (or any attribute) once, but you can set it to a new style that is *based on* the resource style. That means it'll inherit everything that resource style has, plus it'll have whatever you add yourself.

```
<Button Content="Guardar" Width="100" Name="SaveTemplateATM" Click="SaveTemplateATM_Click">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style 
            TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
            BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareButtonStyle}"
            >
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger 
                    Binding="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=UserName}" 
                    Value="0"
                    >
                    <Setter 
                        Property="IsEnabled" 
                        Value="False"
                        />
                </DataTrigger>                                           
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Also, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is at best harmless here, but you don't want it on that binding. What that flag does is to tell the `Binding` how to update the *source* property for the binding (that's `UserName.Text.Length` in this case), when the *target* property changes (that's `Button.IsEnabled` in this case). That doesn't make sense here: Even if `UserName.Text.Length` weren't read-only, that `Binding` would never update it and you wouldn't want it to.

The `UpdateSourceTrigger` flags are for modifying the default behavior of two-way bindings, for example if you were binding the `Text` property of a `TextBox` to a viewmodel string property, the default behavior is to update the viewmodel property when the `TextBox` loses focus. You might want it to update every time the user types a character instead -- in which case you'd give the `Binding` `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

Comment: Thank you! when I use your code I am getting the message `Additional information: A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'BasedOn' property of type 'Style'. A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.`

Comment: @Dimi Hmm. Not good. Will it let you use `StaticResource` instead of `DynamicResource`?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you!

Comment: @Dimi That's a relief!